# Changing background colour in TableCell removes selection colour, makes it hard to read

Tags: java, css, javafx

I made this change:

[Change TableColumn background in TableView, whilst retaining alternating row colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342984/change-tablecolumn-background-in-tableview-whilst-retaining-alternating-row-col/55364704#55364704)

It looks good unselected:

:[image: unselected]

However when you select a cell:

[image: selected]

It looks like this, but I'd like it to act normally when selected/focused.

I'm pretty sure I need to use a style class, however, I don't know what the attributes you need to retain every other feature of a `TableCell` just with a different colour background. Also, do I apply the style class at the Cell level or on the column level?

**UPDATE**

My css file: 
custom.css

```
.customhighlight .table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3);
}

.customhighlight .table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: inherit;
}
```

How do I apply this to one column?

I tried

```
table.getStyleClass().add("customhighlight");
```

However, it changed the entire table.

I tried

```
tableCol.getStyleClass().add("customhighlight");
```

and it did nothing.

I also tried it at the cell level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want:

- All the cells of a column to have a translucent background.
- Those cells, when selected, should look like the default `modena.css` selected look.

  - In other words, replace the translucent background with that darker-blue color and the text becomes white.

You should add a style class to the appropriate cells that you can then use in a CSS file. Here's a small example:

**Main.java**

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var table = System.getProperties().stringPropertyNames().stream()
                .map(name -> new Pair<>(name, System.getProperty(name)))
                .collect(collectingAndThen(toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList), TableView::new));
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true); // Not sure if you're using cell or row selection

        var keyCol = new TableColumn<Pair<String, String>, String>("Key");
        keyCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("key"));
        table.getColumns().add(keyCol);

        var valCol = new TableColumn<Pair<String, String>, String>("Value");
        valCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value"));
        valCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<>() {
            { getStyleClass().add("highlighted-table-cell"); }
            @Override protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                }
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(valCol);

        var scene = new Scene(table, 600, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Main.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

**Main.css**

```css
.highlighted-table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3);
}

/* Needed by cell selection mode */
.highlighted-table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: inherit;
}

/* Needed by row selection mode */
.table-row-cell:selected > .highlighted-table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

.table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

Should work

Comment: That's the thing, I'm going to have to use `getStyleClass.add("something.css")` instead of `setStyle(String)` because you can't target in code (or at least it's messy).

Comment: This should do the trick. Obviously change the colors to what ever makes sense for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can either switch the style in the `updateItem()` method in your `TableCell` by subscribing to the selected property:

```
String style = "-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3);";
setStyle(style);
selectedProperty().addListener((observableValue, value, old) -> {
    if (value) {
        setStyle(style);
    } else {
        setStyle(null);
    }
});
```

Or by using a CSS file:

```
.table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3);
}

.table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: inherit;
}
```

This will color all cells in the table. If you only want to color a single column I would recommend using a custom class for this:

```
getStyleClass().add("customhighlight");
```

Modify the CSS file this way:

```
.table-cell.customhighlight {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3);
}

.table-cell.customhighlight:selected {
    -fx-background-color: inherit;
}
```

All solutions use the default select style for the selected cell, by resetting the background color. The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Comment: How do you apply the css file to one column? I know can do this now`table.getStyleClass().add("customhighlight");` and it changes the entire table, but how do you only affect one column? I tried it on a column and it didn't work.

Comment: @trilogy If you add the class to table cell with `getStyleClass().add("customhighlight");` you have to remove the space between the two css classes, because they are on the same element: `.customhighlight.table-cell`. Or you just replace `.table-cell` with `.customhighlight`.